# Looking for similar words in 2 .txt files

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare two .txt files, where one is dictionary (full names) and another - solid text.

The task is to find out if there is full name from the dictionary in solid text and, if there is, write the last name into a variable.

Write now i'm trying just to create a new file with full name, but new file just fully copy the original solid text, and I really don't understand what is wrong.

```
import re

with open('names.txt') as fh:
    words = set(re.split(r'[ \n\r]+', fh.read())) # set of searched words

with open('solid_text.txt') as file_in, \
     open('hits.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in file_in:
        if any(word in line for word in words): # look for any of the words
            file_out.write(line)
```

The only thing I understand is that I probably digging to the wrong direction and this decision has no right to life.

Comment: _write the last name into a variable_... Which variable in your code stores any "last name"?

Comment: Did you try using `fuzzywuzzy` library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but new file just fully copy the original solid text

Because you are writing the lines from the input file, not any data in your `words` list. If you want to write a name, you need to use that instead.

---

For clarity, I'd rename the `words` as `names`.

```
def get_last_name(name):
    return name.split()[-1]

with open('names.txt') as fh:
    names = set(line.rstrip() for line in fh)

with open('solid_text.txt') as file_in, \
     open('hits.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in file_in:
        for name in names:
            if name in line:
                file_out.write('{}\n'.format(get_last_name(name)))
```

Depending on your expected output, this will write all names that are seen in each line rather than only the first, as using `any()` function would do